# Drop down menu hidden behind

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have created a dropdown menu but the problem I'm having is that when I hover over the top navigation menu, the drop-down menu items are hidden behind the slider and content.
I looked online and trying to figure out the problem but cannot fixes. 
Does anyone can hel me? Please if is possible explain really well.
Thanks in advance,
Helen

Comment: Please add an example of the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely down to the css z-index of the various elements on the page. Higher z-index values will position stuff on top of lower z-index values (providing they have a positioning value). However, you have to bear in mind that child elements cannot gain a higher z-index than their parent element, or at least you can assign the z-index to any value but they will always remain within the parent element at the parent elements z-index value. Most likely the slider on your page has a higher z-index than your header/menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a HTML list e.g. `<ul>` try adding a higher `z-index` to your list to bring it over everything else.

```
.dropdown li {

z-index:999;
position:relative;

}
```

Comment: If you would like to vote my answer as best answer then that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you have position:relative, position:absolute or position:fixed or the z-index will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when working with my drop down menu and it showing up behind the slider. The slider z-index ranged from 1-5 so I made the z-index of the drop down much larger and it now displayed correctly.